# JavaScript - Map of Objects applies function only on last object (possible hoisting issue)

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have created a `WebPage` function that should act as a class.

I have a map of `url` keys and `WebPage` object values and I want to call a method on each object. The method, called `startMonitoring` should set an `interval` to a variable scoped to each object.

However, the interval is set only on the last object and every other object will get the same output when printed afterwards.

Here is my code:

```
export const startMonitoring = (websitesMap) => {
    websitesMap.forEach((website) => {
        website.startMonitoring();
    });
};
export function WebPage(url, checkTime) {
    // other variables
    this.scheduledTask;
    ...
    WebPage.prototype.startMonitoring = () => {
        this.scheduledTask = setInterval(async () => {
            // asynchronous work
        }, checkTime * 1000);
    };
}
```

Comment: `=>` functions don't set `this` the way `function` functions do.

Comment: Every time you create a new instance of `WebPage` you also re-asign the `WebPage.prototype.startMonitoring` function. I doubt that is what you want. Why don't you use a normal class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you are setting the prototype each time your create a new object. So all instances will access the last one you define.

And you will, now, have to use regular functions to have access to the correct `this`.

```
export const startMonitoring = (websitesMap) => {
    websitesMap.forEach((website) => {
        website.startMonitoring();
    });
};
export function WebPage(url, checkTime) {
    // other variables
    this.scheduledTask;
    this.checkTime = checkTime;
    ...
}
WebPage.prototype.startMonitoring = function() {
    this.scheduledTask = setInterval(async function() {
        // asynchronous work
    }, this.checkTime * 1000);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As Pointy said, using the prototype, this would work:

```js
const startMonitoring = (websitesMap) => {
  websitesMap.forEach((website) => {
      website.startMonitoring();
  });
};

function WebPage(url, checkTime) {
  // other variables
  this.scheduledTask;
  this.url = url;
  
  WebPage.prototype.startMonitoring = function() {
      this.scheduledTask = setInterval(async () => {
          console.log('hello', this.url);
      }, checkTime * 1000);
  };
}

const websites = [new WebPage('#', 1), new WebPage('#test', 1)]
startMonitoring(websites);
```

Also, changing the prototype function should also work:

```js
const startMonitoring = (websitesMap) => {
  websitesMap.forEach((website) => {
      website.startMonitoring();
  });
};

function WebPage(url, checkTime) {
  // other variables
  this.scheduledTask;
  this.url = url;
  
  this.startMonitoring = () => {
      this.scheduledTask = setInterval(async () => {
          console.log('hello', this.url);
      }, checkTime * 1000);
  };
}

const websites = [new WebPage('#', 1), new WebPage('#test', 1)]
startMonitoring(websites);
```

Comment: Keeping in mind that when you create methods in a 'class' like this, you are going to have duplicate instances of the method in memory, vs if you used the prototype methodology you would only have one.  Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbqyu096/

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.

Comment: The prototype line should really be outside of the function, otherwise it will re-run for every call.

Comment: Hmm, we lose access to the instance variables then. This maybe should be a non-prototyped function?

Comment: To have access to the `this`, it *should* be a prototype function, and not an arrow function

Comment: Yup, trying to do it in the first snippet, keeping the prototype out of the WebPage function, and I'm not sure it's possible to keep the `this` variables then